# pcap4j failes to capture all trafic

Tags: java, java-8, libpcap, sniffing, pcap4j

I need to capture all traffic from a network interface. right now I'm using the 'Pcap4j' wrapper of 'libpcap' since I've found it convenient.

The code I've made is:

```
try (PcapHandle handle =pcapNetworkInterface.openLive(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                        PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode, -1)) {


         handle.loop(-1,
                    (RawPacketListener) packet -> batch = batch.addAndCheck(packet));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

batch is an implementation of`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and will pile up some packets to send to next step. p.s. while this thread is not done with the batch, next one wont access it to prevent lock waiting.
Some how it fails to capture all the passing packets. and its so random. please provide me some ways to hopefully resolve this issue and thank you in advance.

I've tried different configurations, both PROMISCUOUS and NONPROMISCUOUS modes, variant snap length, capturing by `handle.getNextRawPacket()` and `handle.getNextRawPacketEX()`, all of them failed to work properly.
I've also tried `jnetpcap` which failed as well.